# How to parse suds object saved in txt?

Tags: python, json, xml, soap, suds

I'm working with [Web of Science Python client](https://github.com/enricobacis/wos) which works with suds and I can barely find any useful documentation. I've downloaded over 18k search results (which takes a few hours because of limitations of API) and saved to text files. Now I'd like to parse them.

Example file to be parsed:

```
(searchResults){
   queryId = "462"
   recordsFound = 1
   recordsSearched = 65470148
   records[] = 
      (liteRecord){
         uid = "WOS:000353665400007"
         title[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Title"
               value[] = 
                  "A New Perspective on Instantiation",
            },
         doctype[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Doctype"
               value[] = 
                  "Article",
            },
         source[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Issue"
               value[] = 
                  "3",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Pages"
               value[] = 
                  "448-463",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Published.BiblioDate"
               value[] = 
                  "WIN",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Published.BiblioYear"
               value[] = 
                  "2015",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "SourceTitle"
               value[] = 
                  "LIBRARY TRENDS",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Volume"
               value[] = 
                  "63",
            },
         authors[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Authors"
               value[] = 
                  "Garbacz, Pawel",
            },
         other[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Identifier.Eissn"
               value[] = 
                  "1559-0682",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Identifier.Ids"
               value[] = 
                  "CG9UK",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Identifier.Issn"
               value[] = 
                  "0024-2594",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "ResearcherID.Disclaimer"
               value[] = 
                  "ResearcherID data provided by Clarivate Analytics",
            },
      },
 }
```

1. How to parse these files "back" to python?
2. If it's very hard to do so - how save suds object as XML/JSON?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?I'm researching the exact same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue in another way.

I just created my own Web of Science Web Services client which can print out JSON. You can find it here: https://github.com/mdziezyc/WoSPythonClient